# Changing Paragraph Color With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to design a JavaScript program that changes the text color of an HTML paragraph. `document.getElementById"id1".style.color = "blue";`

in the HTML I have: `<p id="id1">Test</p>`

Whenever I run the code I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at style`
I know there are other articles on this issue, but none of them have solved my problem.

Comment: `document.getElementById` is a `function` that needs to be passed an `id` parameter. Parameters in Javascript are passed to functions inside parentheses `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is syntactically invalid. You need to call the [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method *using parentheses* and pass the argument inside . Try using:

```
document.getElementById("id1").style.color = "blue";
```

**Snippet:**

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958981/changing-paragraph-color-with-javascript/48958992#comment84924740_48958992), you can use the following function to style an element passing its `id`, `property` and `value`.

```js
function style(id, type, modifier) {
  document.getElementById(id).style[type] = modifier;
}

style("id1", "color", "blue");
```

```html
<p id="id1">Paragraph</p>
```

---

Now, regarding the error *`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at style`*, it is evident that the execution of `document.getElementById` with the passed `id` returns `null`, which means that there is no element with the given `id` *(or it hasn't been loaded yet)*.

Comment: That works, but I am trying to create a function so you can pass parameters to fill in the statement.
`function style(bodyid, type, modifier) {
 if (type == "color") {
  document.getElementById(bodyid).style.color = modifier;
 }`
I then run the function from a different JavaScript file like so: `style("id1", "color", "blue")`

Comment: @CadenGrey that sounds like the beginning of a separate question.

Comment: This answer still fails with the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at style`

Comment: `document.getElementById("id1").style.color = "blue";`
This code still works proving that the id exists and is attached to an element.  Maybe the function is being called before the element is generated?

Comment: I fixed it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @CadenGrey. That's what your error means, so yes, the most likely scenario is that your function is called before the element is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the parentheses around the argument of the `getElementById` function. Adding them as in the following snippet will fix it.

```js
document.getElementById("id1").style.color = "blue";
```

```html
<p id="id1">Test</p>
```

Using a editor for your code that provides syntax highlighting or a tool like eslint will help you spot things like this.